# Ionic 3 - App shows blank screen after build with --prod but working with development mode

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen, typescript2.0

After upgrade from app-scripts": "3.1.0" to "3.1.9", my app has broken with --prod flag, I've checked on inspecting device console, but I did not see any errors. Just a blank screen. It worked perfectly on develop mode without --prod flag.

Here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "affiliates",
    "version": "0.0.232",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "config": {
        "ionic_webpack": "./src/config/webpack.config.js",
        "ionic_generate_source_map": "true"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "serve:test": "MY_ENV=test ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "serve:dev": "MY_ENV=dev_docker ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "serve:test_local": "MY_ENV=test_local ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "test": "karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js",
        "test-ci": "karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js --single-run",
        "test-coverage": "karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js --coverage",
        "e2e": "npm run e2e-update && npm run e2e-test",
        "e2e-test": "protractor ./test-config/protractor.conf.js",
        "e2e-update": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --versions.chrome 2.44"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
        "analytics-node": "^3.3.0",
        "brmasker-ionic-3": "^1.0.9",
        "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
        "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
        "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "~4.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.1.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.6.0",
        "flag-icon-css": "^3.0.0",
        "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "moment": "^2.21.0",
        "ng-select": "^1.0.1",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
        "ngx-credit-cards": "^1.0.9",
        "raven-js": "^3.26.4",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "webpack": "^4.29.6",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.21"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.9",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
        "@types/node": "^10.1.2",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "ionic": "3.20.0",
        "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "karma": "^2.0.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
        "karma-webpack": "^3.0.0",
        "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
        "postcss": "6.0.14",
        "protractor": "^5.3.2",
        "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
        "ts-node": "^6.0.3",
        "typescript": "^2.8.4",
        "ws": "3.3.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
                "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser",
            "ios",
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

The app does not show the issue, just a white screen, I guess that is having some incompatible plugins but I couldn't spot where is it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to type

> chrome://inspect/#devices

inside your navbar in chrome and then ionic cordova run android --prod[image: On chrome inspect build]
Here is the mistake. Therefore empty values.

If it won't works, try downgrading your Typescript to 2.8.4.

Hope this help :)